# Select Data based on more than one weekday name in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get data for weekday Sunday and Monday, but it only give me one day's data. I can find answer for one weekday name from a question asked by somebody.

Below are the code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df=pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
 'PurchaseDate':['2007-5-7','2007-6-7','2007-7-7','2007-8-7','2007-9-9','2007-10-7',
    '2007-11-7','2007-12-7','2008-1-7','2008-2-7' ],
    'OrderQuantity':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})

df['PurchaseDate']=pd.to_datetime(df.PurchaseDate)
df.dtypes

df.PurchaseDate.dt.weekday_name.value_counts()  

df1=df[(df.PurchaseDate.dt.weekday_name==('Sunday' and 'Monday'))]
```

The result I got is as in the picture below:

[image]

How would I get data for Sunday and Monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) if want `weekday_name` `Sunday` OR `Monday` - each date cannot be `Sunday` and also `Monday`:

```
df1=df[(df.PurchaseDate.dt.weekday_name.isin(['Sunday','Monday']))]
print (df1)
   CustomerID PurchaseDate  OrderQuantity
0           1   2007-05-07              1
4           5   2007-09-09              1
5           6   2007-10-07              1
8           9   2008-01-07              1
```

Verify:

```
print (df.PurchaseDate.dt.weekday_name)
0       Monday
1     Thursday
2     Saturday
3      Tuesday
4       Sunday
5       Sunday
6    Wednesday
7       Friday
8       Monday
9     Thursday
Name: PurchaseDate, dtype: object
```